# .first returning wrong object type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If you look at the four method calls below, `Service.first` returns a `Service` object, `Salon.first` returns a `Salon` object, etc. But `TransactionItem.first` returns a `Service` object. Why could this be?

```
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :001 > Service.first
 => #<Service id: 147, name: "Fub", salon_id: 2, created_at: "2011-08-10 18:00:07", updated_at: "2011-08-10 18:00:12", price: nil, active: true, archived: true> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :002 > Salon.first
 => #<Salon id: 1, name: "The Cheeky Strut", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, address_id: nil, email: nil> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :003 > Product.first
 => #<Product id: 1, name: "Herbal Essences Shampoo", retail_price: #<BigDecimal:10305f1f0,'0.1E2',9(18)>, wholesale_price: nil, sku: "", salon_id: 2, created_at: "2011-07-08 01:35:48", updated_at: "2011-07-08 01:35:48", archived: false> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :004 > TransactionItem.first
 => #<Service id: 63, created_at: "2011-08-30 20:05:57", updated_at: "2011-08-30 20:05:57", price: #<BigDecimal:10303eba8,'0.18E2',9(18)>> 
ruby-1.8.7-p334 :005 >
```

This is what my `app/models/transaction_item.rb` looks like:

```
class TransactionItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :transaction
  belongs_to :stylist
end
```

Comment: What SQL statement is executed for that last `.first` call? This will be found in your `log/development.log`.

Comment: Are you using single table inheritance?

Comment: The query being run is `SELECT "transaction_item".* FROM "transaction_item" LIMIT 1` - exactly what I would expect. I'm baffled as to where it's getting anything to do with `Service` from. I'm not using any kind of inheritance.

Comment: I have had similar things occur from typos, but your model looks pretty simple. Can you do a TransactionItem.find() on a particular ID and get a transaction item to load?

Comment: Are you sure "transaction" is a good name for relation and model in rails?

Comment: @cgr Interesting thought. `find()` still returns a `Service`. @cutalion It's possibly a bad name but it doesn't seem to cause any problems. I don't see how `TransactionItem` referring to a table with a reserved word could cause it to point to the `Service` table, but I suppose I can't rule out that possibility.

Comment: What if you replace your calls and make, say, Salon or Product first? Salon.first; Product.first; TransactionItem.first #=> ?

Comment: Can we see your Transaction and Service models? Do you have any scopes on TransactionItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blew away the `TransactionItem` table via a migration, then created a brand new migration to re-create it. That seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: And I've now learned that the reason this worked is because, after initially running the `TransactionItem` migration, I had run another migration that did `add_column :transaction_item, :type`, which made things weird, presumably because `type` is a reserved word.